# Why does "dotnet_style_prefer_is_null_check_over_reference_equality_method = true" not recognize "foo == null"?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn, code-cleanup

I decided to switch from `foo == null` checks to `foo is null`. Instead of having to search through all of my code, I set `dotnet_style_prefer_is_null_check_over_reference_equality_method = true` in my `.editorconfig` file, ran `dotnet format`, and nothing happened. I tried `Format Document` in Visual Studio, and it also didn't work.

Looking at the page for [IDE0041](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0041), I see the example:

```
// dotnet_style_prefer_is_null_check_over_reference_equality_method = false
if ((object)o == null)
    return;
```

This seemed to me to mean that it should have worked, and I searched around for an answer before realizing that this check REQUIRES the `(object)` cast. I examined the Roslyn codebase and found that, sure enough, the [UseIsNullCheck](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/tree/14f452081c0e29fd1ddcee043ec38cb51f59605b/src/Analyzers/CSharp/Analyzers/UseIsNullCheck) section only has an analyzer for casting with equality.

Why is this required? Should I have been casting all of my variables to `(object)` all this time when doing null checks, or was this just implementing the IDE0041 examples and not taking the next logical step?

Comment: In my tests "foo == null" works. Have you changed other settings in .editorconfig before?

Comment: Yeah, other settings work as expected when I change them.

Comment: From what you've said, it's not valid. Does it mean that the code inside is not executed at all when the condition of if is met? Or is it that Visual Studio is reporting some error to you?